# How to pass variable From .swf File to .as file?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a main in .as and I load .swf in my .as.It's Working fine,Now I want the take variable From .swf and Pass it Into .as. How can i do this? pls. help!
My .swf file coding

```
function formatMessage(chatData:Object)
{
var number:uint = chatData.user;
trace(chatData.user);
}
private function addText()
    {
_loader = new Loader();
_loader.x=10;
_loader.y=200;
_loader.load(new URLRequest("receive.swf"));//Here i Can Load the Swf.Here how Can i acces  the Variable of number ?
 addChild(_loader);
    }
```

Comment: This variable is DisplayObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to keep in mind is that this will not work across ActionScript VM versions. Meaning only AVM2 and AVM2 can make communication (it is possible between AVM1, but takes more ingenuity).

Add a completion event listener to the `_loader.contentLoaderInfo` property called `onLoad`

```
_loader.x=10;
_loader.y=200;
_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoad);
```

Now with the `onLoad` function will need to extract the loaded content and a little casting.

```
function onLoad(evt:Event):void {
    var target:DisplayObject = LoaderInfo(evt.target).content as DisplayObject; // cast as DisplayObject
    trace("readMe = ", target["your_variable"]); // trace output "your_variable"
}
```

There are cleaner forms of getting this done, but this will allow you extract the value from the nested SWF.

Comment: sir i didnt use nested swf. just i add my swf into .as file,My goal is to retrieve the variable from .swf

Comment: @user993437 - Does your ActionScript file execute? Yes, it does. When you execute the ActionScript you're executing it as a SWF (or in a FLA which in turn is a SWF when compiled). With this line of logic your compiled SWF is loading another SWF called `reciever.swf`. This method of loading one SWF into another is called Nesting. You can think of you own terminology, but for this case it is nesting.

Comment: Thank you sir its very useful information.am using Flash Builder si i cannot trace the value.Is it possible to add the text in addchild()?

Comment: You can create a TextField, add it to the scene and then set the text value. Also, here is a tip for debugging http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/8.2/programLC/programmer/lcds/help.html?content=build_apps_6.html

Comment: Hai John Giotta i have Small problem,i declared the variable(number) inside the formatMessage(chatData:Object).I Cannot access the number,if i declare outside of the function it work.What can i do?How Can i Rectify this problem?

Comment: Yes, change it to `target["formatMessage"]()` and have `formatMessage` `return number`

Answer (score 0):

DisplayObjectContainer(_loader.content).getChildByName("someName");

someName variable must be public, declared in main time line, or main file.

Comment: 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method getChildByName through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject. _loader.content.getChildByName("chatSharedObjectName");while adding this code am getting error like this sir.

Comment: DisplayObjectContainer(_loader.content).getChildByName(..)