# pass the variable from one swf to another actionscript file?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to pass a variable from my main swf to another one that's being loaded in a container in the main swf.I follow this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964347/how-to-pass-variable-from-swf-file-to-as-file),Its Working Fine,My problem is, if i declared the variable within the function i Cannot Access the Variable.AnyBody Help me
(Sorry for Big Coding)
My Coding
My a.swf coding

```
 import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import flash.text.TextField;
 import flash.text.Font;
 var nc:NetConnection = null;
 var textchat_so:SharedObject = null;
 var lastChatId:Number = 0;
 var chatSharedObjectName:String = "textchat";//i can access this variable
 var chatText:String = "";
 var mcCtr:int = 0;
 var align:String="gh";
 var msg:String;// i cannot access this variable
 listChat.visible = false;
 var tickerIdx:int = 0
 {
 nc = new NetConnection();
 nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, ncOnStatus);
 trace("connect: "+ "xxx"); 
trace("connect: "+ "xxx");
    //chatSharedObjectName = connect.soNameStr.text;
    nc.connect("xxx");
   }
 function ncOnStatus(infoObject:NetStatusEvent)
{
trace("nc: "+infoObject.info.code+" ("+infoObject.info.description+")");

if (infoObject.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success")
{
    initSharedObject(chatSharedObjectName);
}

  }


// format the text chat messages
  function formatMessage(chatData:Object)
 {

trace("room"+chatData.txtalign);
var number:String = chatData.user;
 align=chatData.txtalign;
 var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
 myFormat.size =(chatData.txtsize);
 var tf:MarqueeTextField = new MarqueeTextField();
 myFormat.font=chatData.txtfont;
 tf.maxChars=100;
 tf.text =chatData.message ;
 tf.textColor = chatData.user; // <----------------------------------
 tf.defaultTextFormat=myFormat;
 //tf.width = stage.stageWidth / 2;

tf.width = stage.stageWidth;
tf.height = stage.stageHeight

 if(chatData.txtalign=="Left")
 {
 tf.autoSize ="left";
 }
 if(chatData.txtalign=="Right")
{
tf.autoSize = "right";
 }
//tf.x = tf.y = 100;
  //trace(stage.stageWidth);
if( listChat.numChildren >= 0 )
{
   //listChat.removeChildAt( 0 ); 

   }    
   listChat.visible=true;
   listChat.addChild(tf);
   var t:Timer = new Timer(chatData.txtspeed);
  t.addEventListener(
TimerEvent.TIMER,
function(ev:TimerEvent): void
{
    tf.text =tf.text.substr(1) + tf.text.charAt(0);

}


);
 t.start();
 if(listChat!=null)
 for (var i:int = listChat.numChildren-2; i >= 0; i--) {
   listChat.removeChildAt (i);
 }
 msg=chatData.txtalign;
  return msg;
 }

 function syncEventHandler(ev:SyncEvent)
  {
var infoObj:Object = ev.changeList;

// if first time only show last 4 messages in the list
if (lastChatId == 0)
{
    lastChatId = Number(textchat_so.data["lastChatId"]) - 1;
    if (lastChatId < 0)
        lastChatId = 0;
}

// show new messasges
var currChatId = Number(textchat_so.data["lastChatId"]);

// if there are new messages to display
if (currChatId > 0)
{
    var i:Number;
    for(i=(lastChatId+1);i<=currChatId;i++)
    {
        if (textchat_so.data["chatData"+i] != undefined)
        {
            var chatMessage:Object = textchat_so.data["chatData"+i];

             formatMessage(chatMessage);


        chatText += "<p>" + msg + "</p>";
        trace(msg);
            //listChat.htmlText = chatText;
        }
    }

    if (listChat.length > 0)
        listChat.verticalScrollPosition = listChat.maxVerticalScrollPosition;
    lastChatId = currChatId;
}
    }

  function connectSharedObject(soName:String)
  {


textchat_so = SharedObject.getRemote(soName, nc.uri);

// add new message to the chat box as they come in
textchat_so.addEventListener(SyncEvent.SYNC, syncEventHandler);

textchat_so.connect(nc);    


}

 function connectSharedObjectRes(soName:String)
 {

connectSharedObject(soName);
trace(soName);
  }

  function initSharedObject(soName:String)
 {
// initialize the shared object server side
nc.call("initSharedObject", new Responder(connectSharedObjectRes), soName);

}
```

> i Want to  access the variable  inside the function(formatMessage) from b.as

I can Load the a.swf in b.as here my Coding
b.as

```
private function addMessage(){
_loader = new Loader();
_loader.x=10;
_loader.y=200;
_loader.load(new URLRequest("a.swf"));
_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoad);

 function onLoad(evt:Event):void {
var target:DisplayObject = LoaderInfo(evt.target).content as DisplayObject; 
trace(target["msg"]);// here it return null value
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand some slice of your code.

- Param of Message function isn't a variable and it's call like function name.
- You variable msg should be public
- Your function Message don't have a specific return value
- Message(Message); This has no sense!

So, I don't know how your application work but I fix your code as follow:

```
 public var msg:String = "";
 function Message(msg:String):void
 {
     this.msg = msg;// Here you assign directly the message
     trace(this.msg);
 }
```

In the loader code if you want access to msg variable your code should work fine.

Tip: You should use classes concat to your swfs and work with public method for access to these variables. If you have problems you could post more of your code to be more accurate.

I hope this will be usefull to you!

**UPDATE:**
I repeat, I don't know much about how your application is structured, I'd do as follow:

1. Specific in Adobe Flash a document class for your fla project, for example `main.as`
2. Create another Adobe Flash project with a document class that extends MovieClip: For example `Message.as`. This class will export an swf call message.swf
3. Put your loader function in Main.as.
4. Your message class should written like this:

   ```
   public class Message
   {
       private var _msg:String = "";

       //Constructor
       public function Message(msg:String)
       {
           _msg = msg;
       }

       //Getter method
       public function get msg():String
       {
           return _msg;
       }
   }
   ```
5. In Main.as write loader function as you done and load message.swf (pay attention to file system position).
6. When load is complete you can call getter method msg directly on loaded swf:

   ```
   function onLoad(evt:Event):void
     {
      var loadedM:MovieClip = LoaderInfo(evt.target).content as MovieClip; 
      trace(loadedM.msg);
     }
   ```

Comment: i Changed my Coding Sir,Still if Can't understand Please tell me how to access the variable msg in a.swf.Or Explain me wats the problem in my code?

Comment: i want to call the variable msg in b.as

Comment: sir my Swf is working fine,I have problem While retrieving the variable .Again i ll change my full code kindly go through it sir

Comment: Sorry but it's not very clear. Maybe @PatrickS answer can help you!

Comment: i used Shared object sir,i Can retrive the Shared object value in formatmessage function.Now i want to access the variable from format message(a.swf) in b.as.If i cal(variable)"chatSharedObjectName" in b.as its working fine.But i Cannot Call the Variable inside the function

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear but in any case the following line will never work as is:

```
 var target:DisplayObject = LoaderInfo(evt.target).content as DisplayObject; 
 trace(target["msg"]);// here it return null value
```

because DisplayObject doesn't have a msg property, you would need to use either Object or MovieClip.

```
 var target:DisplayObject = event.currentTarget.content as MovieClip; 
 trace(target.msg);// may work better

 //and whilst you're there, you may as well remove the event listener...
```

...almost forgot, in a.swf make sure that your variable is public

```
 public var msg:String = "whatever"
```

Comment: did u understand my Question sir?